# Finding users/records that don't exist in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query to pull a list of student enrollments, and creating a virtual column with logic to assign students with various academic plans to communication groups (`comm_group`). The source view I've been provided to work with pulls one record for EACH academic plan for a student with ANY enrollment in our department. As a result, there are records of enrollments that have nothing to do with our department, because OTHER enrollments that in our department exist. I could just filter out those rows, but I would like to double-check the logic in my virtual column by finding any students who have ALL null values in the `comm_group` column. That would indicate that I missed some plan codes somewhere. Here's some sample data:

| USER_ID | PLAN_CODE | COMM_GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EDA | Ed Administration |
| 1 | CAS | NULL |
| 2 | EDB | Ed Business |
| 2 | BUS | NULL |
| 3 | EDC | NULL |
| 3 | HIS | NULL |

User `3` has an enrollment in `EDC`, so should have a value for that column for `COMM_GROUP` for that row. This means I have left out `EDC` from my `case` statements in my virtual column. I would like to identify all such errors by selecting finding all users who ONLY have `NULL` values.

I'm almost there, but I'm missing something. My code looks like this right now:

```
WITH A AS (long query)
SELECT A.USER_ID
FROM A
WHERE A.USER_ID NOT IN (SELECT A.USER_ID FROM A WHERE A.COMM_GROUP IS NOT NULL)
```

That gives me the user IDs, but really I need to whole row, but I don't want to have to enumerate column from the `with` statement. I tried `SELECT A.*` but I get a `column is ambiguously defined` error.

Is there a way to select all columns from `A`? I'd also be open to other approaches to the problem.

Comment: This works for me. Can you reproduce this on the emp table ?

Comment: The code as it it works, but I need the 15+ other columns, which is why I tried to use `*`. Also wondering if there is a better approach overall.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use analytic `count()`  for your requirements:

```sql
WITH A AS (long query)
SELECT *
FROM (select a.*,count(A.COMM_GROUP) over(partition by a.user_id) cnt from a)
WHERE cnt=0
```

Comment: This answer solved both problems. 1) Cannot select all from the temporary table and 2) Find users who have only NULL for COMM_GROUP.

Answer (score 2):

If you want users with only `NULL` values, you can use aggregation:

```
select user_id
from g
group by user_id
having max(COMM_GROUP) is null;
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working, because COMM_GROUP is a virtual column, so I can't use it in the `having` clause. If I try to use this on the temporary table from `WITH`, I can't select all columns. But it does get the same result I was getting before in a better way. Thanks!

Comment: @CharliePatton . . . `COMM_GROUP` is a column in the data you show in the question.  There is no problem if it is defined in a CTE.

Comment: Right, IF you do the CTE before this and alias it as G, but then I can't get it to select all columns with `select g.*`. I get `Column ambiguously defined`

Comment: @CharliePatton . . . Columns need to have unique names in CTEs and subqueries.

Comment: That seems to be the case, though. I do the CTE as `with A as (long query where COMM_GROUP is created)` and tried following it with both `select *` and `select a.*`. Both produced an error.